# Generate stock path using two stochastic process

Tags: r

I want to generate n stock paths where the stock path depends on two stochastic processes, stock price, and its volatility (Heston model). However, I ran into trouble when trying to fill the stock price and volatility in to my pre-specified matrix. Any suggestions please ?

```
rho <- 0.5
T <- 252
sigma <- 0.3
dt <- 2/T
S0 <- 20
r <- 0.35
kappa <- 50
theta <- 0.35
xi <- 0.2
v0 <-0.7

COV <- matrix(c(1,rho,1,rho), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
W <- rmvnorm(T, , COV)
W_v <- W[,1]
W_s <- W[,2]

Vt <- matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = T)
Vt[,1] <- v0
St <- matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = T)
St[,1] <- S0

for (i in 2:100){
  Vt[i,] <- Vt[i-1,] + kappa* (theta - Vt[i-1,])*dt + xi* sqrt(Vt[i-1,]) * W_v[i-1] * sqrt(dt)
  St[i,] <- St[i-1,]*exp((r-0.5*Vt[i-1,]) *dt + sqrt(dt*Vt[i-1,]) * W_s[i-1])
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

xi is less than or equal to 0.2 is the value of i.
use xi=i=0.2.
i ope it works.
any more reasons.